# Removing scrollbar from iframe on ajax request

Tags: jquery, html

In my iframe src page I am increasing the width and height of div on button click without submitting the page . When the size of div increases there is vertical and horizontal scrollbar coming inside the iframe. 
Is it possible to have browser scrollbar in place of iframe scrollbar when size of div increases inside iframe source page

Regards,
Amit

```
<div id='content'>Test </div>  <button id="submit">Submit</button>




$('#submit').click(function(){

    $('#content').css('height','1400px');
        $('#content').css('width','1800px');
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a defined height `overflow:hidden` to the wrapping element.

Comment: It will not solve the purpose it will hide the overflow content in iframe. My requirement is not to hide the content but to have browser scroll bar in place of iframe scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using jQuery, you can try:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-iframe-resizer